# Can you pass agent-specific parameters to a wandb sweep?

Tags: wandb

I would like to be able to pass a particular parameter with a different value on each agent in my wandb sweep.

Comment: Would you mind posting your code here?

Comment: @JimmyZhao, there is no code because I couldn't figure out how to do it.
This is what it usually looks like: 

```yaml 
program: train.py
method: bayes
metric:
  name: validation_loss
  goal: minimize
parameters:
  learning_rate:
    min: 0.0001
    max: 0.1
  optimizer:
    values: ["adam", "sgd"]
```

Source: https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/define-sweep-configuration

I would like to pass a different environment variable to each agent in order to configure which GPU they should use.